# How to mask the value of a member variable in a List of objects using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table which I'm displaying in a grid. I'm being asked to mask the value of certain column if another value in that same row meets some condition.

Take for example:

```
public class Container
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Volume { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<Container> myContainerList;
// Imagine some code to populate the object
```

Currently, I'm masking the Volume field like so:

```
var filteredList = from container in myContainerList
                   let vol = container.Name.ToUpper().Contains("SPECIAL") ? 
                                                       -1 : container.Volume
                   select new Container()
                   {
                       Name = Name,
                       Volume = vol
                   };
```

This successfully masks the volume of any container with the name "special" in it, but this seems inefficient to me.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: you could move the masking part after you get the collection on the application server before data binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add another property to the Container class:

```
public string MaskedVol
{
  get 
  { 
    return (Name.IndexOf("SPECIAL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1 ) ? "--" : Volume.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good solution which would prevent probably unneccessary creation of `Component` instances.

Comment: For better clarity, I would change comparison to `>= 0` and return order to `? Volume : -1`. And note, in original code `Volume` is not a string, it's a number.

Comment: You're right -- I was returning Name, rather than Volume.  I updated the code to show the correct thing being returned.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sean that adding a readonly property is probably the best option. If you don't want to change the `Container` class, than you can simplify your linq query a little bit:

```
var filteredList = myContainerList.Select(c => new Container {
    Name = c.Name,
    Volume = c.Name.ToUpper().Contains("SPECIAL") ? -1 : c.Volume
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does this seem inefficient to you?
For each item, exactly one check is performed, so I can't see any way of speeding up the process.

You can make it a bit faster and less resource-consuming by using `IndexOf` instead of creating a new string with `ToUpper` and calling `Contains`.

Then decide whether it is `Component`'s responsiblity to mask `Volume`.
If it is, declare a special property in it to remove clutter in query:

```
public class Container
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }

    public int MaskedVolume {
        get {
            return (Name.IndexOf ("SPECIAL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                ? Volume
                : -1;
        }
    }
}
```

If it's not `Container`'s responsibility to know about masking, I agree with [Elian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901732/how-to-mask-the-value-of-a-member-variable-in-a-list-of-objects-using-linq/4901852#4901852) that lambda is a better fit than `let`:

```
var filteredList = list.Select (c =>
    new Container {
        Name = c.Name,
        Volume = (c.Name.IndexOf ("SPECIAL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                     ? c.Volume
                     : -1
    });
```

What alerts me, though, is the fact you create another instance of `Component` just to display it in a list view. Is this true? It seems like `Component` is part of business logic, and surely from business logic point of view new `Component`s don't get created each time a list view is populated.

Maybe you should reconsider your solution in this case. Can you give us more details about how `Component` is used in the application?

Comment: The only caution I'd make in your example (extension, etc.) is that if this is a linq-to-sql, it might not translate correctly to SQL and throw exceptions (just a guess, haven't tested it).  And aside from that, lambdas certainly make this more readable than "let's" IMO as Elian Ebbing posted.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about it. Naturally, if it was LINQ to SQL, our extension method would be out of question, thanks for pointing this out!